# Using parts pullers for the installation

Tags: repair, compressor

*Background:* I have a car that is way overdue for replacement, 1997 Lexus ES300 that also recently had its compressor seize up. While looking for used cars, considering the limited travel nowadays I thought maybe I should research on a cost-effective fix.

Checking some prices:

- bypass pulley ~$50 on eBay
- remanufactured compressor ~$120 eBay
- used compressor ~ $60 Pick n Pull

I see that row52 allows to contact [part pullers](https://row52.com/PartsPullers/) to get the parts and ship them, presumably many of them are also car mechanics as well.

Can we request for local pullers to fetch the part and also do installation (ofc. charging labor costs) rather than just getting the part? Or would it be inadvisable and better to just order a part and use proper auto repair shops for the installation?

Comment: You can *request* pretty much anything you want, but who knows if it will fly where you live. It boils down to who you talk to and what they are willing to do. Most shops won't allow you to bring in parts for them to put on the vehicle. Some will, but I've found them far/few between. I'm not really sure this question is a fit for this site, considering it's really not about repairing your car, but how to go about having someone else do it. Also, what is "row52"? I'm clueless.

Comment: Row52 is the linked site.  shipping costs might be high, so find a local junkyard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is opinion-based: I'd go with a used part from a local wrecker. It is cheaper, and original quality is often better than aftermarket (rebuilt or new). For non-critical parts, which this is, it is normally well worth it.

Most shops I've dealt with will install your parts, ones that don't normally overcharge you significantly for parts anyway. They may, however, charge you a bit higher rate.

In addition to Row52 you can also check out car-part.com for the listing in your locality. On car-part.com you can see which vehicle (condition/mileage) they will be pulling the part from.